# Having Issue with CSS styling and select boxes with buttons

Tags: css, angularjs

Im currently attempting to style up a series of simple multi-select boxes.

https://next.plnkr.co/edit/wBfAMTYvPPjWncsY?open=lib%2Fscript.js&deferRun=1

This is the HTML

```
<div class="listBoxSpacing">
    <span class="listBoxHeaders">Days Of The Week:</span>
    <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="day as day.day for day in vm.daysOfWeek track by day.day" ng-model="vm.daysOfWeekSelected"></select>
    <br />
    <button>Select All</button>
  </div>
  <div class="listBoxSpacing">
    <span class="listBoxHeaders">Dates Of The Month:</span>
    <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="date as date.date for date in vm.datesInTheMonth track by date.date" ng-model="vm.datesInTheMonthSelected"></select>
    <br />
    <button>Select All</button>
  </div>
  <div class="listBoxSpacing">
    <span class="listBoxHeaders">Days Of The Week:</span>
    <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="day as day.day for day in vm.daysOfWeek track by day.day" ng-model="vm.daysOfWeekSelected"></select>

    <button>Select All</button>
  </div>
```

This is the Javascript...

```
 vm.daysOfWeek = [
    {day: 'Monday'},
    {day: 'Tuesday'},
    {day: 'Wednesday'},
    {day: 'Thursday'},
    {day: 'Friday'},
    {day: 'Saturday'},
    {day: 'Sunday'},
  ];
  vm.datesInTheMonth = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < 32; i++) {
    vm.datesInTheMonth.push({date: i});
  }
  vm.daysOfWeekSelected = [];
  vm.datesInTheMonthSelected = [];
```

This is the CSS

```
.listBoxHeaders {
  display:block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.listBoxSpacing {
  float:left;
}
.listBoxSpacing:nth-child(n+2) {
   margin-left:30px;
}
.listBoxSpacing button{
  width: 100%;
}
.listBoxSelectStyle {
  width:100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

As can be seen in the code above, the first and second ones (with the br tag) align with the header properly. However, the third one with the same code as the first one doesn't align with the heading properly (without br tag).

Im curious as to why this behavior is so, could anyone link me to docs/explain the concept so I can understand this behavior in the future?

Comment: I have added the code directly into the question, apologies I thought the plunker would be more beneficial since it is a visual problem. Thank for letting me know :)

Comment: why do you have to float an element to give spacing? if you want to use leftover space you can change display property to inline-block.

Comment: @vssadineni thanks for the advice, I have switched these around in my actual code environment now (not the plunker). Any insight into the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    :root {
      font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    body,
    nav,
    section,
    article,
    main,
    aside,
    header,
    figure,
    div,
    p,
    a,
    span,
    h1,
    h2,
    h3,
    h4,
    h5,
    h6,
    ul,
    ol,
    li,
    table,
    thead,
    tbody,
    tfoot,
    tr,
    th,
    td,
    dl,
    dd,
    dt,
    blockquote,
    fieldset,
    legend,
    input,
    textarea,
    select,
    select option,
    button,
    label,
    img,
    footer {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    html,
    body,
    input,
    select,
    select option,
    label,
    textarea,
    button {
      font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
      font-size: 100%;
    }
    nav,
    section,
    article,
    main,
    aside,
    header,
    figure,
    footer {
      display: block;
    }
    dl,
    dd,
    dt {
      margin: 0;
    }
    blockquote {
      margin: 0;
      padding-left: 1.75em;
    }
    fieldset {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.25em;

      border: 0 solid transparent;
    }
    body {
      color: rgba(23, 23, 23, 0.99);
    }
    body,
    ul,
    figure {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }
    svg {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;
    }
    iframe {
      overflow: hidden;

      margin: 0.02em;

      border: none;
    }
    a {
      text-decoration: none;

      color: inherit;
    }
    p {
      margin: 0;

      line-height: 1.75;
    }
    hr {
      display: -ms-flexbox;
      display: flex;

      min-width: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      margin: 0;

      border-top: 0.125px solid rgba(10, 10, 10, 0.25);
      border-right: 0;
      border-bottom: 0;
      border-left: 0;

      font-size: 0;
      line-height: 0;

      -ms-flex-preferred-size: 100%;

      flex-basis: 100%;
    }
    img {
      width: 100%;
      height: auto;

      border: 0 solid transparent;
    }
    [ng\:cloak],
    [ng-cloak],
    [data-ng-cloak],
    [x-ng-cloak],
    .ng-cloak,
    .x-ng-cloak {
      display: none;
    }

    h1,
    p {
      font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    .listBoxSpacing {
      display: inline-block;
      width: auto;
      vertical-align: top;
    }
    .listBoxSpacing:not(:first-child),
    .listBoxSpacing:not(last-child) {
      margin: 0 1em;
    }
    .listBoxHeaders,
    .listBoxSelectStyle,
    .listBoxSpacing button {
      width: 100%;
      display: block;
    }

<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="lib/style.css">
    <script src="lib/script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="plunker" ng-cloak>
    <div ng-controller="MainCtrl as vm">
      <div class="listBoxSpacing">
        <span class="listBoxHeaders">Days Of The Week:</span>
        <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="day as day.day for day in vm.daysOfWeek track by day.day" ng-model="vm.daysOfWeekSelected"></select>
        <button>Select All</button>
      </div>
      <div class="listBoxSpacing">
        <span class="listBoxHeaders">Dates Of The Month:</span>
        <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="date as date.date for date in vm.datesInTheMonth track by date.date" ng-model="vm.datesInTheMonthSelected"></select>
        <button>Select All</button>
      </div>
      <div class="listBoxSpacing">
        <span class="listBoxHeaders">Dates Of The Month:</span>
        <select class="listBoxSelectStyle" multiple size="7" ng-options="day as day.day for day in vm.daysOfWeek track by day.day" ng-model="vm.daysOfWeekSelected"></select>
        <button>Select All</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: reference for the code]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to add all that information, I have tested it and it worked as described (and shown). Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

br creates space between lines (break) and start new line. But I do not see any alignment issues here with reference to the image.

[image: br creates space between lines (break) and start new line. But I do not see any alignment issues here with reference to the image.]

Comment: by the way I took the image from your plunker reference.

Comment: You see how the third option is wider than the title, adding br fixes that for some reason and im trying to understand why that is the case. Does that make sense or should i reword it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

I copied the css and the html as is., In to my local system. **div.listBoxSpacing** , I removed the **float** property replaced it with **display:inline-block**. I request you use some reset.css and avoid floats. As I strongly believe Float is causing this problem. if you see the titles are aligned now without and with **br'** s.

[image: screenshot from local system.]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, could you provide a plunker, edit my plunker or a snippet of the code you used. I have tried to implement what you showed in the plunker I provided and the spacing issue was still present. The image looks great though!